# How to select single word in URL in iOS 13?

Tags: text, url, cursor, gesture, ios

Given a text with a link inside:

[image]

Prior to iOS 13, i could long press a word that was not part of the URL to select the word, then drag the finger over a word in the URL to select only that word of the URL, without opening the URL.

In iOS 13 this is not possible anymore. When dragging the selection of a single word, the selection gets extended with additional words.

How can I select a single word in a URL to copy the word without opening the URL?

Comment: try double tap on that word? https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/06/14/ios-13-overview-text-editing-gestures/ "Cursor navigation
Moving the cursor is even faster and more precise — just pick it up and drag it to where you want. It will automatically snap to lines and between words." from https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13/features/

Comment: That works! Amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double tap on that word.

https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/06/14/ios-13-overview-text-editing-gestures/ says:

> - Select a word: double-tap on it.
> - Select a sentence: tap on the text with three fingers.
> - Select a paragraph: tap on the text with four fingers.
> - Bubble menu: bring up the shortcuts menu by tapping once with three fingers.
> - Select multiple contiguous items: tap with two fingers, then drag to quickly select emails, files and folders.